# Where did the lockscreen clock go?

Tags: 13.04, lock-screen, clock

I am using raring dailies, and one thing that my eyes liked was the lockscreen. I really liked the clock. A simple thing, but still really good?

Now it is suddenly gone. Did they really remove it from raring?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand exactly what you miss, I hope that my [repo on GitHub](https://github.com/Gelma/xlockmore-for-13.04) can solve your problem.

Ciao,
Andrea

Comment: Quote from a famous AU user "if all people were that fast :)"